# plotly.express showing a real mess of a graph

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Python newbie here

I've been working on a data analysis project that require some pieces of dataviz. I really want to use plotly.express library for it's interactiveness but the vizualization is a complete mess.

For this graph, I want to show position variations of F1 pilots for each lap and I have a perfect dataframe for that but the result is this:

[DF on plotly.express](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK47k.png)

For comparison, when I run the very same dataframe on seaborn I get this:

[same DF on sns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdrg8.png)

It appears that plotly.express is show multiple positions for the drivers on a same lap witch is impossible. I can't figure out what's going on, any tips?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: try passing the dataframe sorted by the x axis, plotly express doesn't sort implicitly
df_laps_brazil2012.sort("LAP")

Comment: Post a [mre] including sample data. And post code in text.

Comment: I could not reproduce the ".sort" :(

Comment: I made a minimal reproducible example. If you guys could take a look and help me figure out why my sorting is not working out, I'm very thanksfull https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1M_2SYLW2OAOjsMEuINdIdpTqWQLpt6B8?usp=sharing